# Ограничение на конструктор new(), обобщенное программирование

Tags: c#, generics

Рассматривая тему ограничения обобщений, не понял, каково практическое применение ограничения на конструктор. Вот есть пример класса, например студента:

```
class Student
{
    public Student(){}
}
```

А вот есть обобщенный класс:

```
class Class2<T> where T : new()
{
    public T typeTinClass2;

    public Class2()
    {
        typeTinClass2 = new T();
    }
}
```

И допустим еще какая то тривиальная вызывающая часть программы:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Class2<Student> vasiliy = new Class2<Student>();

    }
}
```

Вопрос простой - в каких реальных  ситуациях это можно использовать? Допустим есть ограничение на класс и интерфейс, зачем они нужны осознать не сложно, потому что сразу понятно когда и как это может быть использовано. Но как можно использовать ограничение на конструктор? Да, есть возможность в обобщенном коде создать экземпляр класса такого типа, который был передан в <>, я так же понимаю что есть например такая вот возможность:

Console.WriteLine(vasiliy.typeTinClass2.someField);

Но в каких ситуациях это вообще может потребоваться?  Какая задача должна передо мной стоять, что бы мне потребовалось использовать ограничение на конструктор?

Comment: Ответ вроде бы тоже тривиальный: когда внутри обобщенного класса надо создавать объекты типа `T`,  то есть вызывать его конструктор `new T();`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Но в каких ситуациях это вообще может потребоваться?

Например, когда при описании класса-фабрики, который имеет какой-нибудь метод типа

`T CreateObj<T>()`

Если ты не установишь это ограничение, то не сможешь внутри метода вызвать метод `new` => тебе придется обращаться напрямую через рефлексию(ограничение позволяет переложить это на плечи компилятора) к конструктору без параметров, которого может и не быть=> программа может упасть.

Comment: А разве `new T()` не транслируется в вызов `Activator.CreateInstance<int>()`, который можно делать и без `new()`?

Comment: Надо бы IL-код глянуть. Мне почему-то кажется, что нет, так как дженерики преподносили чуть ли не панацею от всех болезней, где даже значимые типы не упаковываются.

Comment: *Надо бы IL-код глянуть.* https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgjANgAQwExICoFMDOwkDeAsAFBLkqKZIByWA7gDwYB8AFAJRL0AWWATlkwgkAOwackAXhZiGmTgG5SFSsgxIAsgE86TVpJmUAdAEEAxsDAA3AIbAA9v2MBhQfawBJUXlujzWMzsHMokAL6kQA

Comment: @PerSerAl, транслируется, да, т.е. скорость такая же, как и при явной рефлексии. Но тут преимущество в том, что компилятор проверит наличие конструктора без параметров при компиляции и мы не упадем в рантайме